# Replacement for std::sync::Semaphore since it is deprecated?

Tags: rust

The documentation says it is deprecated. What's the system semaphore? And what's the best replacement for this struct now?

> [Deprecated since 1.7.0: easily confused with system semaphore and not used enough to pull its weight](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/std/sync/struct.Semaphore.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

System semaphore refers to whatever semaphore the operating **system** provides. On POSIX (Linux, MacOS) these are the methods you get from `#include <semaphore.h>` ([man page](https://www.mankier.com/0p/semaphore.h)). `std::sync::Semaphore` was implemented in rust and was separate from the OS's semaphore, although it did use some OS level synchronization primitives (`std::sync::Condvar` which is [based](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9a0b7749665d925d8f533756149deba74f2db88b/library/std/src/sys/unix/locks/pthread_condvar.rs#L6) on [`pthread_cond_t`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_init) on linux).
`std::sync::Semaphore` was never stabilized. [The source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/src/std/sync/semaphore.rs.html#52-55) for Semaphore contains an unstable attribute

```rust
#![unstable(feature = "semaphore",
            reason = "the interaction between semaphores and the acquisition/release \
                      of resources is currently unclear",
            issue = "27798")]
```

The issue number in the header specifies [the discussion about this feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27798).

The best replacement within `std` is either a `std::sync::CondVar` or a busy loop paired with a `std::sync::Mutex`. Pick a `CondVar` over a busy loop if you think you might be waiting more than a few thousand clock cycles.

The documentation for `Condvar` has a good [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html#examples) of how to use it as a (binary) semaphore

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar};
use std::thread;

let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new()));
let pair2 = Arc::clone(&pair);

// Inside of our lock, spawn a new thread, and then wait for it to start.
thread::spawn(move|| {
    let (lock, cvar) = &*pair2;
    let mut started = lock.lock().unwrap();
    *started = true;
    // We notify the condvar that the value has changed.
    cvar.notify_one();
});

// Wait for the thread to start up.
let (lock, cvar) = &*pair;
let mut started = lock.lock().unwrap();
while !*started {
    started = cvar.wait(started).unwrap();
}
```

This example could be adapted to work as a counting semaphore by changing `Mutex::new(false)` to `Mutex::new(0)` and a few corresponding changes.

Comment: it looks like Semaphore is already removed. No longer in version 1.40 at least based on https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67606#issuecomment-568914561

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken - semaphore was never "stabalized" in the first place - it was only available on a nightly compiler, never the stable one. Breaking changes are allowed to happen in the nightly compiler, just not the stable one. I have now edited my original answer.